# Running multiple django apps in apache https server one in / and another in /app2

Tags: django, apache, ssl, mod-wsgi, multiple-instances

I am trying to deploy two django apps in same server ssl port 443. While I comment following three lines in first block app2 is running while commenting in second block app1 is running and when uncommenting in both block both apps is not running and showing Internal Server Error and apache error log showing

> mod_wsgi (pid=48352): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/app1/app1/wsgi.py'.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ......
WSGIProcessGroup ...... 
WSGIScriptAlias ......
```

my default.conf file VirtualHost *:443 block is as follows

```
    Alias /static /var/www/html/app1/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/app1/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/app1/app1>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>


    WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-path=/var/www/html/app1
    WSGIProcessGroup app1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/app1/app1/wsgi.py
```

```
    Alias /museum/static /var/www/html/app2/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/app2/static>
           Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/app2/app2>
           <Files wsgi.py>
                   Require all granted
           </Files>
    </Directory>

    #WSGIDaemonProcess app2 python-path=/var/www/html/app2
    #WSGIProcessGroup app2
    #WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/html/app2/app2/wsgi.py
```

for the above code app1 is running perfectly

```
    Alias /static /var/www/html/app1/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/app1/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/app1/app1>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>


    #WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-path=/var/www/html/app1
    #WSGIProcessGroup app1
    #WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/app1/app1/wsgi.py
```

```
    Alias /museum/static /var/www/html/app2/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/app2/static>
           Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/app2/app2>
           <Files wsgi.py>
                   Require all granted
           </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess app2 python-path=/var/www/html/app2
    WSGIProcessGroup app2
    WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/html/app2/app2/wsgi.py
```

for the above code app2 is running perfectly

I want to run both servers together.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put each app in an individual virtual host in Apache and do a rewrite to distinguish to which one to route which request.